# Listview is showing only after I hot reload or refresh in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, asynchronous

I almost tried everything. My functions async, my snapshots async. I'm using future builders, My carousel slider works fine. I don't need to hot reload or refresh for carousel slider. But for my listview builder i need to refresh every time to fetch data. I tried connection state status for if statment but connection state getting done quickly (before data completely loaded). So my pictures and my datas not coming without refresh or hot reload.

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:video_games/model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_games/send_models.dart';
import 'package:video_games/views/details_view.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<Autogenerated> apiCall() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=5ac29048d12d45d0949c77038115cb56&page=1'));

    return Autogenerated.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  int slideractiveindex = 0;
  var urlImages = [];
  var uniqueImages = [];
  var growableList = [];
  var listId = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    clearCache();

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<Autogenerated>(
            future: apiCall(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              List<Results>? data = snapshot.data!.results;
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CarouselSlider.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                      urlImages.add(data![index].backgroundImage);
                      uniqueImages = urlImages.toSet().toList();

                      final urlImage = uniqueImages[index];
                      return buildImage(urlImage, index);
                    },
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        autoPlay: true,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {}),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 32),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          FutureBuilder<Autogenerated>(
            future: apiCall(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print(snapshot.connectionState);
                print(urlImages.length);
                List<Results>? data = snapshot.data!.results;

                return ListView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    growableList.add(data![index].name);
                    listId.assign(data[index].id);

                    // String? id = data[index].id.toString();
                    // urlImages.add(data[index].backgroundImage);
                    uniqueImages = urlImages.toSet().toList();
                    final urlImage = uniqueImages[index + 1];
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: ListTile(
                        tileColor: Colors.black12,
                        leading: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
                                      id: '${data[index].id}',
                                    ),
                                  ));
                            },
                            child: buildImage2(urlImage, index)),
                        title: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '${data[index].name}',
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text('Rating : ${data[index].rating}'),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 20,
                                ),
                                Text('Release : ${data[index].released}'),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 19,
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildImage(String? urlImage, int index) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: urlImage!,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          key: UniqueKey(),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget buildImage2(String? urlImage, int index) {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: urlImage!,
          key: UniqueKey(),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void clearCache() {
    DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
    imageCache!.clear();
    imageCache!.clearLiveImages();
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

This is my error part

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 17
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[image: Before i reload]
[image: After i reloaded]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FutureBuilder` removes boilerplate code. [see](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Let's say you want to fetch some data from the backend on page launch and show a loader until data comes.

**Tasks for ListBuilder:**

- Have two state variables, `dataFromBackend` and `isLoadingFlag On`
- launch, set `isLoadingFlag = true`, and based on this, show `loader`.
- Once data arrives, set data with what you get from backend and set
  `isLoadingFlag = false` (inside `setState` obviously)
- We need to have a `if-else` in widget creation. If `isLoadingFlag` is
  `true`,show the `loader` else show the `data`. On failure, show error
  message.

**Tasks for FutureBuilder:**

- Give the async task in `future` of Future Builder
- Based on `connectionState`, show message (loading, `active(streams)`,
  `done`)
- Based on `data(snapshot.hasError)`, show view

**Pros of FutureBuilder**

- Does not use the two state variables and setState
- Reactive programming (FutureBuilder will take care of updating the
  view on data arrival)

**Example:**

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
future: _fetchNetworkCall, // async work
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
   switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
     case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Loading....');
     default:
       if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
       else
      return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
  },
)
```